# I would like to use itext7 when I have imported the dependecy with maven successfully.But it always with the error"NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: maven, itext7

I have use eclipse(version4.4.1) to create a maven project(version3.5.4),and the jdk version is 1.8. The dependency about itext7(version7.0.3) already import into the maven project successfully,but while run the project there is always with the wrong "**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument**".I have tried to repeate the step to create the project and add the jar "**bcpkix-jdk15on-147.jar，bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar**".But the wrong I couldn't to solve it.Is there any wrong with my project?The pictures is about my project's pom  file and error.
[image]
Hope for your replay!

enter image description here

Comment: That version of Bouncy Castle is not compatible. You need to check the pom file of the sign module of iText to verify the compatible version. But normally Maven does this automatically for you.

Comment: I’m truly grateful for your help. I have change the Bouncy Castle  version into 1.54 but it still incorrect. And I have done maven clean,but it doesn't works.

Comment: 1.54 is the wrong version. You probably have more than one version.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have checked the Bouncy Castle's  lastest version is 1.60 and update to my maven project but it still have the error the same as before.

Comment: 1.60 is too new for the version of iText you are using. Have you checked the pom file?

Comment: yes, when checking the pom file,I couldn't idntify the right Bouncy Castle version for my project. How to select the correct version according to the pom file?